# Destroying a specific session

Tags: php, session

I have made a site with a login system using PHP to start a logged in session with the id of the logged in user. I have a core.Inc.php file in which I Used session_start(); and when I proceed to login using that logged in session this session is set until destroyed by logging out. Now I have register.php (But this could be any php page) and I have set this page up in a way that if I go to that page but I'm already logged in it sends me back to index.php and it starts a session called alert_ar_loggedin. Then, in my index page i have an if statement saying that if this session is active (I check that with a funcion) I include this alert through another php. Now I want to destroy that session in a way that the next time I come to a page or I refresh it that the session is no longer active. I can't use session_destroy() Because that also destroys the logged in session. How should I do this? Or is there a better approach for such an alert?

Comment: use `session_unset()`

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju session_unset() dont accept any param, it ll release all the session variable .... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

```
unset($_SESSION['your_session_variable_name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
unset($_SESSION['name']);
```